# How can I save Large Json Data to sql database using Entity Framework SaveChanges()?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to save a large json data (approx 2-3 MB) text file size data using Entity Framework.

```
Dim data As New jsonData With { .ID = _id, .jsonData = jsonDataFromFile }
MyContext.DataContext.JSONTempTable.Add(data)
MyContext.SaveContext("SaveJsonData")
```

This code works perfectly fine for small json data, but if the Json is larger (file size 1.5 mb), then it won't save in database. It does not throw any error. In database, `jsonData` column is of `varchar(max)` datatype.

How can I save large JSON in `varchar(max)` data type column?

--Edited
yes I do have try catch with logging but it won't go to catch block. 
In entity framework that property is like below

```
Public Property jsonData As String
```

Comment: Are you sure its not just taking longer than you expect? How do you know there is no exception? Is there a try/catch with message or maybe its swallowed with an empty catch?

Comment: How is that property defined in your EF model?